# How to use enum with attributes Reflections?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i am open your ideas: i really dislike this usage . how to convert enum to string via attributes. But please be careful my question StringValueAttribute have more than one constructor also fields. How to develop GetStringValue Extention method via StringValueAttribute ??? Best Regards...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace UsingAttributes
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UserType.Login.GetStringValue());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public enum UserType : int
    {
        [StringValueAttribute("xyz", "test")]
        Login = 1
    }
    public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string UserName { get; protected set; }
        public string PassWord { get; protected set; }
        public decimal Something { get; protected set; }

          public StringValueAttribute(string Username, string Password,decimal something)
        {
            UserName = Username;
            PassWord = Password;
            Something  =something;
        }
        public StringValueAttribute(string Username, string Password)
        {
            UserName = Username;
            PassWord = Password;
        }
       public StringValueAttribute(string Username)
        {
            UserName = Username;

        }

    }

    public static class Extentions
    {
        public static String[] GetStringValue(this Enum value)
        {
            // Get the type
            Type type = value.GetType();

            // Get fieldinfo for this type
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

            // Get the stringvalue attributes
            StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

            // Return the first if there was a match.


                PropertyInfo[] pi = attribs[0].GetType().GetProperties();
                String[] Vals = new String[pi.Length];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (PropertyInfo item in pi)
                {
                   // Vals[i] =  How to return String[] 

                }
            // i dislike return values one by one : attribs[0].UserName 
           //return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].UserName : null; // i have more values
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that `decimal` **cannot** be used as an attribute argument. You can use `double` or you can use a string and then convert it to a decimal.

Your GetStringValue() should work if you replace

```
    // Vals[i] =  How to return String[]
```

with

```
    Object val = item.GetValue(attribs[0], null);
    Vals[i++] = val != null ? val.ToString() : "";
```

If you are using C# 4.0, you don't need three constructors. You can use optional arguments:

```
public StringValueAttribute(string Username, string Password = "nothing", double something = 0)         
{             
     ...
}
```

And in older versions of C# you can use the `OptionalAttribute`:

```
public StringValueAttribute(string Username, [Optional] string Password, [Optional] double something)         
{             
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to say this is an odd way to do it, but you'd just need to change your code to something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object[] Objects = UserType.Login.GetStringValue();
            for (int x = 0; x < Objects.Length; ++x)
                Console.WriteLine(Objects[x].ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class Extentions
    {
        public static object[] GetStringValue(this Enum value)
        {
            // Get the type
            Type type = value.GetType();

            // Get fieldinfo for this type
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());

            // Get the stringvalue attributes
            StringValueAttribute[] attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];

            // Return the first if there was a match.

            object[] Vals = new object[3];
            Vals[0] = attribs[0].UserName;
            Vals[1] = attribs[0].PassWord;
            Vals[2] = attribs[0].Something;
            return Vals;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But i have no idea UserName,Password or something

Comment: Then just add a function onto the attribute class that gives you the info. And if that's not possible just add some reflection calls to get the value.